# Perl regex String part to array

Tags: regex, arrays, string, perl, split

I have a string:

```
"2012-szept-17 02:55 - someproblem: 192.167.1.1 since - $somevariables[0] $morevariables[-1]"
```

and I want to get these out of it into an array

```
$somevariables[0]
$morevariables[-1]
```

The problem is that these variables can be named anything else and they could be anywhere in the string. The only thing I know about them is that they start with `$` and have `[sg]` in the end.

This is the furthest I got with the regexp

```
my @fuu = $notimsg =~ m/(\$.+\[.+\])/g;
```

The problem is that the expression is making this into `"$somevariables[0] $morevariables[-1]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they must be valid variable names (identifiers), then try

```
m/(\$\w+\[[^]]+\])/g
```

As @Borodin points out, if you really want to make sure you match only identifiers (and not something strange like `$3abc[12]`), you can use

```
m/(\$[a-z_]\w*\[[^]]+\])/gi
```

Comment: This allows variable names starting with a digit. The correct regex is `/(\$[a-z_]\w*\[[^]]+\])/i`

Comment: I figure the array at the end makes it rather unlikely to crop up...after all, his problem is avoiding the spaces. Nevertheless, I'll edit to add.